# Joining tables before or after union all?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, hive, union

I have 3 tables. 2 are similar.

```
table1/table2
col1 string
col2 string
col3 integer

table3
51 columns. strings, ints, doubles, dates
```

I am curious which will be faster.

```
with s1 as(
  Select *
  from table1
  union all
  Select *
  from table2
)
select *
from s1
inner join table3 t3
on s1.col1 = t3.col4
```

or

```
with s1 as(
  Select *
  from table1 t1
  inner join table3
  on t1.col1 = t3.col4
),s2 as(
  Select *
  from table2 t2
  inner join table3
  on t2.col1 = t3.col4
)
Select *
from s1
union all
Select *
from s2
```

Tables are not partioned or indexed. I would like to know how this works for both
hive and oracle.

Edit 02.02.2017
I tried to check it in hive. Started at aproximately the same time.

```
union before join
Time taken: 539.593 seconds

jbu
Time taken: 603.071 seconds
```

Unfortunately after I decided to check the result a couple hours later

```
jbu
Time taken: 308.205 seconds
```

The result varied depending on how busy the cluster was((

Comment: I think this is better asked at dba.stackexchange

Comment: The simple is answer is to test it - make sure to clear buffer cache between tests. And when you say 'not indexed' do you mean not even an index supporting the primary key ? (Assuming you have a PK - that is).

Comment: @Brite I don't have the possibility to test in in orace. Because data is in hdfs. There are no PKs in hive( lets assume table 1/2 don't have PKs in oracle either. I will test it in hive tomorrow, but that's a whole day before I find out =P

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see is that the 2nd query scans table 2 twice. But without any execution plan info, that's just a guess. As others have said, why not test and let us know; perhaps share the execution plans!

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely 1st one is faster .
`with s1 as(
  Select *
  from table1
  union all
  Select *
  from table2
)
select *
from s1
inner join table3 t3
on s1.col1 = t3.col4`

Comment: Would you care to explain why? As it stands now, this looks like graffiti, not an Answer.